# html-5 range slider max and min value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using html-5 slider

```
      <input type="range" .. />
```

I want to slider's `min` and `max` values on its left and right side respectively . How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="range" min="20" max="80" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8Lzx/)

Also the following attributes can be applied to `input type="range"`

- **max** - specifies the maximum value allowed
- **min** - specifies the minimum value allowed
- **step**  - specifies the legal number intervals
- **value** - specifies the default value

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display `min` and `max` values on its left and right, just print there:

```
10 <input type="range" min="10" max="20" /> 20
```

You could use css too, though its not widely supported.

```
input[type="range"]:before {
    content: attr(min) " ";
}
input[type="range"]:after {
    content: " " attr(max);
}
```